# Live Clock in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a looping PowerPoint for a kiosk. This presentation needs a live clock on every slide. I have figured out a way to do this, but unfortunately it won't work for an unmanned presentation.

I currently have a shape on each slide that is assigned to the macro below. The shape is the entire size of the slide, and contains no fill. The only way I know how to execute the macro is with the "Action" option and mouse over or mouse click. I have it assigned on mouse over and it works for every slide when I move the mouse. Is there a workaround either in PowerPoint or VBA to have this run independently?

```
 Sub digitalClock()
 Dim time As Date
 Dim minutes As Integer

 time = Now()
 minutes = 60

 time = DateAdd("n", minutes, time)

 Do Until Now() = time
  DoEvents

  With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
  End With

 Loop

 End Sub
```

EDIT: (I dont know if this is the proper way to do so, I am sorry)

This almost works, but it doesn't adhere to my shape on the slide that has proper text formatting like the last macro. It simply inserts the time over top the current slide. I also have to manually advance, and it will not run on the next slide.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim i As Integer
Dim time As Date
Dim minutes As Integer

time = Now()
minutes = 60
time = DateAdd("n", minutes, time)
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition

Do Until Now() = time
DoEvents

With ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
End With
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It'd be worth having a look here for several ideas that should help (specifically the OnSlideShowPageChange event.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840063/onslideshowpagechange-not-running-in-presentation  
In case it's not mentioned there, sometimes the event will fail to fire in some PPT installations; in that case, add an ActiveX control to the first slide, move it off the slide if you like.  For some bizarre reason, this seems to wake up the event handler

Comment: Reading over everything now. Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just wanted to thank @Steve Rindsberg for his help with this issue. I was working on a similar thing trying to get a timer countdown to automatically update as text on a shape for every slide where where the shape was present. This is the code I ended up with:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim diff As Double
    Dim endDate As Date: endDate = DateSerial(2022, 5, 29)
    Dim days As Integer
    Dim sld As Slide
    
    diff = endDate - Now()
    days = Int(diff)
    
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With sld
            On Error Resume Next
            .Shapes("Shape Countdown").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Minute(diff - days) & " minutes"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next sld
End Sub
```

And it worked fine on one computer automatically running when I started the Slide Show, but then when I tried on my laptop, the macro wouldn't run automatically until it had been manually run from the Developer tab. Was racking my brain searching for an answer then I find Steve Rindsberg simple solution to just add a random ActiveX object to the 1st slide, and it works now.  Thank you thank you

Comment: [Bows] Glad it worked for you.  I'm not the person who discovered this little trick, so can't take credit. But can't remember who I learned it from, so can't GIVE proper credit, unfortunately.